# Как правильно распарсить html код?

Tags: c#, html

Есть `html` код, использую `CsQuery`,  собственно как правильно вытащить селекторы из этого кода. Интересует, как мне выдрать Менеджер по грузоперевозкам и Имя Фамилия с описанием. С самим `CsQuery` ясно все, только  не соображу пока как с селекторами работать.

```
<div class="title-">
  <a href="/resume/204907034" class="title-" id="s-204907034">
    <h2 data-ga="resumeListItem">Менеджер по грузоперевозкам</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="lb-container" id="lb-container-204907034" style="top: -4px;"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- <div class="comments-count"></div>-->
  <p>Имя Фамилия, 357 лет (13.05.1981)</p>
  <p>полная занятость, полный рабочий день, готов к командировкам </p>
</div>
```

Comment: привязаться к `data-ga="resumeListItem"` пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167 да пробовал, но что то не показывает ничего, иерархия тут какая то

Comment: хм, мне казалось, что селекторам все равно какая там иерархия, странно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код работает с приведенным в вопросе html.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
CQ html = text;

var h2 = html["div.title-"]["a.title-"]["h2[data-ga='resumeListItem']"].Text();
//       html["div.title- > a.title- > h2[data-ga='resumeListItem']"]

Console.WriteLine(h2);

var ps = html["div>p"];
foreach (var p in ps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.FirstChild);
}
```